# What do the red fox and scorpion tail represent in these movies?

Tags: back-to-the-future, the-monster-squad

The same red fox and scorpion tail logos appear in *Back to the Future* and *The Monster Squad*:

| [image: screencap] | [image: screencap] |
| --- | --- |

Has anyone noticed this same image before? Is this just an image directors throw in their movies as an inside thing? It's definitely odd.

At the end of *The Monster Squad* (1987), it suddenly sure felt like it was the same set as *Back to the Future*'s (1985) Hill Valley town. I even made a joke that it would be funny if the car came back speeding by on *The Monster Squad*. Then I noticed the red fox that was also on the hut in the *Back to the Future* scene in the parking lot of the Twin Pines Mall where Doc is shot. It's the same red fox symbol in both films, though: in *Back to the Future*, it shows two angles of the hut and two red fox images and a symbol like a black "L" over a white background. I rotated the image upside down and noticed the red fox now became a red scorpion tail with the number 77 in black and white.

This is my take on it:

In the STRONGS bible CONCORDANCE for the number 77 is:
Hebrew: אבץ
Transliteration: 'ebets
Pronunciation: eh'-bets
Definition: From an unused {root} probably means to gleam; conspicuous;
Transliteration: adapanos
Pronunciation: ad-ap'-an-os
Definition: From G1 (as a negative particle) and G1160; costless that is gratuitous: - without expense.
KJV Usage: without charge (1x).

Comment: Its not at all clear what question you are asking here - particularly the bible concordance stuff.  What are you actually asking?

Comment: Has anyone noticed this same image before? Is this just an image directors someone's throw in their movies as an inside thing? Please let me know what you all think about this. It's definitely odd.

Comment: But what is the relevance of all the bible concordance stuff?  It confuses the question.   You're rotating blurred images and reading *far* too much into it.

Comment: I think it's a good observation you made, and it merits a question that can be objectively answered (that it turned out to be product placement is something you clearly didn't anticipate, and your question should not be judged by that). However, I agree with iandotkelly that you're reading too much into it, and that, moreover, your interpretation should be posted as an answer (which will likely get downvoted for being pure opinion), and not as part of your question.

Answer (score 5):

This is the logo of a real company called [Fox Photo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_Photo), who sold photographic equipment and developed photos, back in the days before digital cameras. If their logo seems unfamiliar, it's probably because they went out of business in 2001. (I must admit I'd never heard of them either until I started researching this question.)

Their appearance in these two movies is almost certainly just [product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement). There's no inside joke or Biblical references here. As for set re-use, parts of both films were shot at [the Universal Studios Lot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Studios_Lot), so it's possible.

Here's a much clearer shot of the logo as shown in *The Monster Squad*:

[image]

And here's the best shot I could find of the Fox Photo hut as depicted in *Back to the Future*:

[image]